# ¿Cómo hacer un pull request de comits históricos a otro repositorio?

Tags: git, git-commit, github, git-push, git-fork

He estado trabajando en un *fork* de un proyecto de `GitHub` y estoy muchos *commits* adelante del repositorio original.

Quise integrarlo pero me solicitaron enviarlo en varios *pull request* en vez de todos los *commits* en uno solo( pues eran más de 20 ).
¿Existe alguna manera de hacer un *pull request* de *commits* que no contenga los últimos commits que he realizado en mi repositorio?

PD:Perdón por el spanglish, pero la verdad no sé como se traducen esos términos al castellano.

Comment: no creo que sea apropiado traducirlos, seria como traducir _if_ a _si_

Comment: Me parece una excelente idea aplicar cursiva a los términos que deben dejarse en inglés. Mejor que escribir después la traducción entre paréntesis.

Comment: Es lo que me comenta la comunidad experta en el meta que es lo más correcto. Saludos desde México.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si entiendo tu pregunta, puedes usar rebase:

```
git checkout master 
git pull
git checkout <branch>
git rebase master
```

Así tendrás tu branch arriba del master actual.

O si quieres usar solo algunos ciertos comits, puedes hacer una copia de master, y después cherry-pick de tu branch, solo los comits que quieres en tu pull request.

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout -b branch_nuevo
git cherry-pick <revisión 1> <revisión 2> ... <revisión N>
```

Así tendrás un branch nuevo con sólo los comits que quieres, y lo puedes usar como normal en GitHub.

Comment: Gracias en la noche probaré, perdona por hacerte esperar :)

Comment: De momento cree un brazo a una revisión vieja, pues entiendo que el cherry pick debe de empezar desde una versión obsoleta, en caso de ser así favor de actualizar su respuesta con:
git checkout QA
git branch --track i8n fa6065e107028a9d2a1160b2d77259640413c1b8
git cherrypick <revisión 1> <revisión 2> ... <revisión N>

Answer (score 2):

La solución que yo encuentro más divertida a este problema es la del rebase interactivo, que además sirve en muchas otras situaciones. El procedimiento es el siguiente:

1. Creas una rama nueva con un nombre descriptivo de lo que hace tu pull request.

   ```
   $ git checkout -b nombre-de-la-rama
   ```
2. Haces el rebase:

   ```
   $ git rebase --interactive origin/master
   ```

Eso te abre un editor, en el que estan listados los commits que estarías moviendo, ahí podés hacer varios cambios, entre ellos borrar lineas lo cual descarta los commits que borrás. Cuando terminas de editar el archivo, guardas y se reescribe la historia (de esta rama nueva que creamos, así que tus commits originales quedan ahí por si todo falla).

Después haces push de esa rama y hace un nuevo pull-request con la parte que te interesa.

Es más comodo que el cherry-pick cuando los commits que te interesan son más de 2.

### Conflictos

Si algunos de los cambios que querés conservar depende de alguno de los que no, vas a tener conflictos como si fuera un merge y se solucionan de la misma manera.

Comment: jojo menos mal que tengo que hacer dos brazos así pruebo las dos soluciones gracias! :3

Comment: Como mencionas siempre es útil, pero en futuras ocasiones prefiero dejarlo como último recurso. Mil gracias :)